# Include the selected password in confirmation mail

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net Identity and sending a confirmation link by mail like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
                       new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id,
                       "Confirm Account", "Confirm your Account, click the link <a href=\""
                       + callbackUrl + "\">här</a>.");

                    ViewBag.Message = "Email sent "
                + "more text.";

                    return View("Info");
                }
```

I want to include the password they select on the registration in the mail (plain text). How can I do that?

Comment: `model.Password` contains the value. But are you really sure you want to be doing that?

Comment: Why would you send them their password? they have just typed it and know it. Password in an email is a security threat you don't want to create.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
  var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = 
  model.Email };
  var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
  if (result.Succeeded)
  {
   string code = await 
   UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
   var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account",
   new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
   await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm Account",  
   "Confirm your Account, click the link <a href=\""
   + callbackUrl + "\">här</a>.your password is :  "+ model.Password);

   ViewBag.Message = "Email sent " + "more text.";
   return View("Info");
  }
 }
}
```